# In the Pursuit of Happyness what is on the wall at the top of the stairs?

Tags: the-pursuit-of-happyness

[image]This is in a house in the San Francisco Bay Area.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a lever that opens the front door to the building. Fairly common in 19th century Victorian houses in San Francisco.

[image: Illustration showing how mechanism works, though the lever would be at the top of the stairs.]

Illustration showing how mechanism works, though the lever would be at the top of the stairs.

[Link to patent for a door opener mechanism](https://www.google.com/patents/US1267307).

Comment: So what's the point of this device? Saving the homeowner a few extra steps from the door handle?

Comment: It's used from upper floors in a house so you don't have to run all the way downstairs to let someone in the front door. The diagram shows how the contraption works in a general way. The lever wouldn't be so close to the door when installed.

Comment: More similar photo here.    https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/san-francisco/san-francisco-apartment-quirks-door-levers-old-school-ice-boxes-and-more   Nice answer.